# Verses when holding the Sefer Torah

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, torah-service

On Shabbath morning, when someone hold the Sefer Torah, he starts by saying "Shema Israel".

After saying "Shema Israel", he (in some communities) says a verse starting with "Ehad Elo-henou, gadol...". When he puts the Sefer Torah back in the Hechal, he says a verse starting with "Mi Hu Ze Melekh...".

I looked on my Siddur and I did not find these two verses. What are they exactly?

Comment: êtes-vous français?

Comment: Not all communities say Shma and Echad. For example, many Yekkes do not have this custom.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ashkenazi custom, on Shabbat and holidays, the chazzan (leader) says "Shema Yisrael Ado-nai Elo-henu Ado-nai Echad" - שמע ישראל ה' אלקינו ה' אחד. ("Hear, Israel: The Lord is our God, the Lord is one.") This verse is from [Deuteronomy 6:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9970/jewish/Chapter-6.htm#v=4). The congregation then repeats this verse.

Then, the chazzan says (again followed by the congregation): "Ehad elo-henu, gadol adonenu, kadosh shemo" - אחד אלקינו גדול אדוננו קדוש שמו. ("One is our God, great is our Lord, holy is His name.") This verse does not have a Scriptural source.

When putting back the Torah, a psalm is recited by all. At all times other than Shabbat mornings, this is [Psalm 24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16245/jewish/Chapter-24.htm). The last verse is "Mi Hu Zeh Melekh Hakavod, Ado-nai Tzeva-os, Hu Melekh Hakavod Selah" - מי הוא זה מלך הכבוד ה' צבקות הוא מלך הכבוד סלה. ("Who is the king of glory, the Lord, Master of legions, He is the king of glory, Selah.")

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it was "Ehad elo-henu, gadol adonenu, kadosh 'some word" shemo". I am not conformtable with so I do not know what this word is but it sounds like "venura".

Comment: @RabbeinouYoel At High Holiday times many congregations add the word ונורא Venora ("and awesome") in the spot you mention.

Comment: Thank you. About Mi Hu Zeh, I am sure that it starts with "Mi Hu Zeh melekh, lifne melokh melekh". Is it the same one?